# Set scroll to end of Image (change default value)

Tags: c#, android, scroll, xamarin

I add my big ImageView (6000 x 800) in small HorizontalScrollView (800x800).
By default, the slider is on the left (at the beginning of the image).

How I can set this scroll at the end of ImageView? Can I change default value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HorizontalScrollView.FullScroll doesn't work for you?

```
HorizontalScrollView scrollView1 = new HorizontalScrollView(this);
var handler = new Handler();
handler.PostDelayed (() => scrollView1.FullScroll (FocusSearchDirection.Right), 100);
```

Comment: Sorry, but I can't use FindViewById, because I create HorizontalScrollView programmatically:
HorizontalScrollView scrollView1 = new HorizontalScrollView(this);
How I can set Id "hsv" to my scrollview?

Comment: Doesn't matter. It was just an example. Just use your variable instead of hsv.